# Conditional probability (two dice)

Tags: probability

Two dice are rolled, what is the probability that die 1 shows a 5 given that a 10 has been rolled?

I'm a little confused as to how to solve this exercise.
I get two different results depending on how I go about solving it.

Method 1 (logic):
The probability of having die 1 show a 5 when two dice are rolled is 1/36.
The probability that a 10 is rolled is 3/36.
Now I put this in the basic probability format and it gives me (1/36)/(3/36)=1/3.

Method 2 (baye's theorem):
P(A/B) = P(A)xP(B/A) / P(B) = 1/36 x 1/6 (bc if die 1 shows a five and I need to get a 10, then die 2 needs to show a five also, hence 1/6) / (3/36) = 1/18

Comment: P(1st die is 5)=1/6 your text was a bit unclear on that. We get P(1st die is 5 | sum is 10) = P( both dice 5) / P(sum is 10) = (1/36)/(3/36) = 1/3. Your Baye's them calculation must contain an error.

Comment: $P(B|A)$ is not $\frac 1{36}$  you get to assume that one die is a 5.  It is not the same as the chance of rolling double 5's outright.

Comment: Another approach to is to discard all rolls that do not sum to 10, at the first step.  Leaving (6,4) and (5,5), and (6,4) is twice as likely as doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that our probability space is $(\Omega, \mathbb P)$ where

$$\text{sample space: }\Omega = \{\{1,1\}, \{1,2\}, ..., \{6,5\}, \{6,6\}\}$$

$$\text{probability measure: }\forall \omega \in \Omega, \mathbb P(\omega) = \frac{1}{36}$$

We want to compute

$$P(\text{5 is rolled} | \text{sum is 10}) \tag{*}$$

Observe that the event $\text{5 is rolled}$ corresponds to the sample outcomes $\{5,1\}, ..., \{5,6\}$ and the event $\text{sum is 10}$ corresponds to the sample outcomes $\{5,5\}, \{4,6\}, \{6,4\}$.

Hence,

$$(*) = P((\{5,1\} \cup ... \cup \{5,6\}) | \{5,5\} \cup \{4,6\} \cup \{6,4\})$$

$$ = \frac{P((\{5,1\} \cup ... \cup \{5,6\}) \cap (\{5,5\} \cup \{4,6\} \cup \{6,4\}))}{P(\{5,5\} \cup \{4,6\} \cup \{6,4\})}$$

$$ = \frac{P(\{5,5\})}{P(\{5,5\} \cup \{4,6\} \cup \{6,4\})}$$

$$ = \frac{P(\{5,5\})}{P(\{5,5\}) + P(\{4,6\}) + P(\{6,4\})}$$

$$ = \frac{1/36}{3/36} = 1/3$$

---

Another way to look at it is to change our probability space

$$\text{sample space: }\Omega = \{\{5,5\}, \{4,6\}, \{6,4\}\}$$

$$\text{probability measure: }\forall \omega \in \Omega, \mathbb P(\omega) = \frac{1}{3}$$

So if we want to compute $P(\{5,5\})$, by definition of our probability measure, we have 1/3.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $B$ is the event a $10$ has been rolled, and $A$ is the event Die 1 shows a $5$. Then $\Pr(A)=1/6$, or, if you prefer, $6/36$,  $\Pr(B\mid A)=1/6$,  and $\Pr(B)=3/36$.

Substituting and simplifying, we get that $\Pr(A\mid B)=1/3$. The two methods give the same answer.

Comment: Thank you.
However, both methods give the same answer when method 1 considers the probability of getting die 1 to show 5 as 1/36; and method 2 considers the probability of getting die 1 to show 5 as 1/6.

The problem itself is a bit unclear, as jdods pointed out, but even if we consider the same probability of getting die 1 to show a 5 for both methods, we still get a different answer, why is that? What am I not reasoning correctly?

Comment: Method 1 is in essence uses the definition of conditional probability, $\Pr(A\mid B)=\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$. It would be better to make $A$ and $B$ explicit, since informal arguments can distressingly often lead to error. Method 2 is essentially the same, except that it uses explicitly $\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(A)$ to compute $\Pr(A\cap B)$.